# how to navigates to new Ui component in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

i am using **angular 2 RC 3 and router 3.0.0-alpha.8** and try to navigate to another UI component i am using **PathLocationStrategy**  but it only update url but not UI

```
export const HomeRoutes: RouterConfig = [
{path:'search/:searchId',component:SearchListingComponent} ]
```

and inside my headerComponent i have this mathod

```
goToSearch(searchId: string): void{
  this.location.go('/search',searchId);}
```

which should navigates to search-listing page but it only update url. 
[image]

home.routes.ts file:

```
export const HomeRoutes: RouterConfig = [
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
{path:'search/:searchId',component:SearchListingComponent},
{ path: 'listing/:id', component: ListingPageComponent}
     ]
```

app.routes.ts file:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
...HomeRoutes,
...UserRoutes,
...ProfileRoutes,
...LandownerRoutes
     ];
  export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
provideRouter(routes),
AUTH_PROVIDERS
      ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use router to navigate

```
  //in header component 
    constructor(private router:Router){}
    goToSearch(searchId: string): void{
  this.router.navigate(['/search',searchId]);}
```

Comment: i did that but i had log error message says ** Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'SearchComponent' **

Comment: I assume you want to replace home route. You need to defined this route in your app.routes.ts.  Can you give details on that

Comment: `export const HomeRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
    {path:'search/:searchId',component:SearchListingComponent},
    { path: 'listing/:id', component: ListingPageComponent}
]`

Comment: Do you have a config on parent component of this. If you have show that and move search route definition  there.

Comment: If you want to replace search in main portion in home then you have to have router-outlet tag there and add router directive in directive in home component metadata

Comment: Search- listing  is different page, i have search bar in home page and i want to navigate to search-listing page once user click search button and carry search value to Search-listing page, so basically it acts like **href**

Comment: I get that but do you have <router-outlet></router-outlet> define in template of component where you want to see search listing. Also you need to add route paths to same competent.  can you show more code. Your HTML template in which home component is getting loaded and routes for that comp

Comment: it is kind messy because i  am updating old angular 2 projects and routing is wired. home component doesn't have  <router-outlet></router-outlet> but app.component does. however in app.component there are  reference header component in header section and footer component in footer section and  main section there is  <router-outlet></router-outlet> so header and footer display always

Comment: i am real confuse and i don't know how angular 2 route works and how i can make my home component display in main page and where i should include <router-outlet></router-outlet> in my app.component

Comment: From what you said this should be working can you try to route to SearchComponent without search Id. I want to see if issue is with search comp or search list comp. I hope you have kept leading '/'  on search in navigate method.

Comment: it works . <router-outlet></router-outlet> load correctly and replacing content of  main page but leaving header component as is which i don't want because i want to design new searching page this is why i used PathLocationStrategy in first place to load whole new component true

Comment: As per your structure your app.component has header and footer referenced rather than routed. You can try using ngIf to hide them. Like *ngIf="router.url != /search"

Comment: I though angular 2 has a better way to do this rather than using ngif. I thought PathLocationStrategy used for this purpose It is like $location in angular 1.x

Comment: Indeed. But your app is not structured to leverage the same.  I would make your current app.componet and search.comp as sibling and add a new mainapp.comp. I will remove search routing from app.comp and add new routes in mainapp.routes. 1 default for app.comp and / search for search.  I hope your are getting where I am going

Comment: i am totally agree with you but i do not know to implement that also i am not fan of webpack angular template which has been used by my project